# Servlet Filter called multiple times

Tags: authentication, filter, servlet-filters

A servlet filter which is used for authentication is called multiple times in the same request.Which intern doesn't allow to authenticate the user as the browser keeps loading infinitely.

Below is the web.xml-

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Filter Implementation class-

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

AuthenticationService service = new AuthenticationService();
service.validateAuthentication(request, response);

if(!response.isCommitted()) {
    doFilter(request, response);
}

}
```

validateAuthentication which intern does the azure authentication.

`2019-07-08 01:50:45,927 INFO  [com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority] (pool-235-thread-1) [Correlation ID: 424f42b1-15e9-44e7-b2d8-84b82fe89132] Instance discovery was successful
2019-07-08 01:50:46,166 ERROR [com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext] (pool-235-thread-1) [Correlation ID: 424f42b1-15e9-44e7-b2d8-84b82fe89132] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable failed.: com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error_description":"AADSTS500112: The reply address 'http://docker.azurewebsites.net/' does not match the reply address 'https://docker.azurewebsites.net/' provided when requesting Authorization code.\r\nTrace ID: e6b5f37f-4bcd-4233-aab4-e98d725f7400\r\nCorrelation ID: 424f42b1-15e9-44e7-b2d8-84b82fe89132\r\nTimestamp: 2019-07-08 05:50:46Z","error":"invalid_client"}
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:128)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:928)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:70)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:38)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call(AdalCallable.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Comment: Hi, this is a plain servlet filter, nothing jsf related. And if you have lots of requests that match the filter it will be called multiple times, that is just how it works

Comment: Not sure why this request is infinite. Added the stacktrace.

Comment: Check if it is recursive in http requests or inside in the servletfilter... Might be that an authentication error redirects to an error page which is processed by the servlet filter in which authentication fails etc... this is in 90% of the  cases the cause

Comment: That may not be the case, the code works fine locally, but fails only when deployed in azure. As per log the error is -                                                   The reply address `http://docker.azurewebsites.net/` does not match the reply address `https://docker.azurewebsites.net/` provided when requesting Authorization code.`https://docker.azurewebsites.net` is the one registered in azure.

Comment: And why not? I see an error in the stacktrace that might result in... errors... which might result in loops... Exclude things... If you have the error locally to and it works there, the error is not related and can be removed from the question. Debug... Narrow down...

Comment: I had both of these issues in an asp.net environment. The infinite loop (my website https to my website http to login.microsoftonline.com) only happened when I made the initial browser request to my website over http (not https) so a simple http->https redirect avoided that.The second case (the one with the AADST error) happened to me because my site was behind a load balancer that handled the HTTPS encryption, so my site saw incoming requests as plain http, so that's how the RedirectUri went out in the request. I had to manually change the outgoing Uri value to force it to https.